# How to allow event propagation in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, z-index

It seems that AngularJS default prevents event propagation. [Here is a test on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/29427/).

As you can see from the link above, the `div` covering the links prevent the event propagate the the `div` under it, so the links are not working when clicked. This is just a testing case, in the real situation, the `div` got other function and need to be there, so removing the `div` is not an option.

So, how can I make the mouse click propagate to the links under `div`?

---

The code in case you don't want to click on the link, or the link becomes dead link some day in the far future. (And to fit the rules on Stack Overflow)

HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="unrelated">
    <a href="http://stackoverflow.com">Stack overflow
    </a><a href="http://www.goole.com">Google</a>
  </div>
  <div class="scope" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="testing">
    <div class="half-cover" ng-click="leftShow = false" ng-show="leftShow == true">
      Click to remove one
    </div><div class="half-cover" ng-click="rightShow = false" ng-show="rightShow == true">
      Click to remove one
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('testing', ['$scope', MyCtrlFunction]);
function MyCtrlFunction($scope) {
    $scope.leftShow = true;
    $scope.rightShow = true;
}
```

CSS

```
.container {
  position: relative;
  height: 300px;
  width: 500px;
  background-color: white;
}
.unrelated {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.unrelated a{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  line-height: 300px;
  text-align: center;
}
.scope {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1000;
}
.half-cover {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  line-height: 300px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, it's very confusing example, but problem is not about propogation

Problem that you hide your sides, but your `.scope` still overlay with height 100%;

So I do following:

HTML

```
 <div class="container" ng-app="myApp">
  <div class="unrelated">
    <a href="http://stackoverflow.com">Stack overflow
    </a><a href="http://www.goole.com">Google</a>
  </div>
  <div ng-controller="testing">
    <div class="scope {{ checkShow() }}" >
       <div class="half-cover" ng-click="leftShow = false" ng-show="leftShow == true">
         Click to remove one
        </div><div class="half-cover" ng-click="rightShow = false" ng-show="rightShow == true">
      Click to remove one
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$scope.checkShow = function(){
   if($scope.leftShow == false && $scope.rightShow == false) {
       return 'hidden-scope';
   } else {
      return ''
   }
}
```

It really confusing, because `ng-if` was not working somehow, weird interpolation erros when I tried `{{rightShow && leftShow ? '' : '.hidden-scope'}}`, so I decided to end it with `$scope.checkShow`

CSS

```
.hidden-scope {
   height: 0;
}
```

JSFiddle [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Legendary/hwdqyd6s/1/)

Answer (score 0):

This is not an issue regarding event propogation.. your `div` (the one with `scope` class and `ng-controller`) is super-imposed on the div with `unrelated` class because of **`z-index: 1000`**.

One of the (simple) ways you can access stuff below is by decreasing the `z-index`. So, applying an `ng-class` that does it for us. ***This can be any condition or function.***

```
ng-class="{'hideit': !leftShow && !rightShow}"
```

where,

```
div.hideit {
  z-index: -1
}
```

[**forked working fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/tbq2y2am/2/)

Comment: As I mentioned, the div got function in my real case. Although you didn't remove it, making `z-index:-1` is also not okay as the div lost the function of overlaying `div`.

Comment: @cytsunny you cannot access what's below it otherwise. And you can easily have overlaying div back too by using a similar approach of `ng-class`